# ¿Cómo puedo combinar filas de un dataframe con datos en común?

Tags: r

tengo un data frame que es de la siguiente forma:

```
   ID        COMUNA cumple POSICION
1   1   PROVIDENCIA     si        3
2  12         ÑUÑOA     no        2
3   3        COLINA   <NA>       12
4   9     QUILICURA     si       11
5   8          <NA>     si       NA
6   1          <NA>   <NA>       NA
7   4 indepemdemcia     no       56
8   3          <NA>     no        4
9  11       florida   <NA>       NA
10  8     los andes     si        5
```

necesito agruparlos por `ID` y que las columnas se completen, es decir, que solo quede una fila con el `ID=8` pero que esta quede completa, que las dos filas con `ID=8` están incompletas, intenté usar `grupo_by`, pero no me resultó, corrió sin problemas el comando pero no me dio ningún resultado, ojala puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Bienvenida Evelyn Giovanska Silva a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

No sé si exactamente lo que buscas, pero podrías quedarte con los primeros valores no `NA` que tenga cada grupo:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(first(na.omit(.))))

# A tibble: 7 x 4
     ID COMUNA        cumple POSICION
  <int> <chr>         <chr>     <int>
1     1 PROVIDENCIA   si            3
2     3 COLINA        no           12
3     4 indepemdemcia no           56
4     8 los andes     si            5
5     9 QUILICURA     si           11
6    11 florida       NA           NA
7    12 ÑUÑOA         no            2
```

Comment: creo que funcionará para lo que necesito, te puedo consultar por que la columna comuna de la fila 4 quedó como NA si en el df original en la fila 10 aparece el dato?

Comment: Por que importe tus datos pero olvidé que el texto "<NA>" de tu ejemplo no se importa realmente como NA.   En tu caso, si el dato es NA debería funcionar bien